# Why is my function not identifying the end of the region correctly?

Tags: region, point

I have the following function, adapted slightly from [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_examples.html):

```
;; Insert text around a region. In this case, it's
;; the LaTeX code environment from the listings package 
(defun wrap-code (start end)
  "Insert a \begin{code} and \end{code} around a region."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start) (insert "\\begin{code}")
    (goto-char end) (insert "\\end{code}")
    ))
;; Assign its shortcut
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'wrap-code)
```

If I then select a region and apply my function, it inserts the `\end{code}` at the wrong place:

```
\begin{code}while :; do
      echo this is\end{code} a test
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because when you insert your first chunk of code after `start`, `end` remains constant and now point in the middle of something (since more characters have been added before it).

A quick solution for your use case is to insert text at the end before:

```
;; Insert text around a region. In this case, it's
;; the LaTeX code environment from the listings package 
(defun wrap-code (start end)
  "Insert a \begin{code} and \end{code} around a region."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char end) (insert "\\end{code}")
    (goto-char start) (insert "\\begin{code}")))
;; Assign its shortcut
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") 'wrap-code)
```

A more general solution would involve [markers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overview-of-Markers.html) instead of positions

Answer (score 3):

`end` is a number, an exact position in the buffer. So when you go to `start` and insert text, the rest of the text gets pushed forward, and `end` is no longer pointing to the end of "done" but rather still the position "done" used to be at.

The easiest solution is to just insert the end{code} text first, the the begin.